# how to decode hex code of html entities to text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, text, hex, decode

I am facing a difficulty in converting hex values of string characters to normal test values
for example hex value of  `&#x27;` to sting is `'` i.e an apostrophe.

Another values of hex characters can be found on this link : http://character-code.com/.

Can someone please tell me if a javascript method exists to do so or should I be using some external javascript library plug-in for this purpose?

I have already tried using `URIencode` and `URIencodecomponent` but no luck

Answer (score 8):

You can use the host–provided parser to insert the entity in an element, then get back the *textContent* (or *innerText* where supported instead):

```
var el = document.createElement('span');
el.innerHTML = '&#x27;';

console.log('&#x27; is a ' +  (el.textContent || el.innerText));  // &#x27; is a '
```

Of course that won't work for entities the browser doesn't support.

#### Edit

To turn the above into a function:

```
var entityToText = (function() {

  // Create a single span to parse the entity
  var span = document.createElement('span');

  // Choose textContent or innerText depending on support
  var theText = typeof span.textContent == 'string'? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

  // Return the actual function
  return function(entity) {
    span.innerHTML = entity;
    return span[theText];
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `String.fromCharCode` - but you will first need to convert the hex value (base 16) to an integer (base 10). Here's how you would do that:

```
    var encoded = "&#x27;";
    var REG_HEX = /&#x([a-fA-F0-9]+);/g;

    var decoded = encoded.replace(REG_HEX, function(match, group1){
        var num = parseInt(group1, 16); //=> 39
        return String.fromCharCode(num); //=> '
    });

    console.log(decoded); //=> "'"
```

To convert the decimal back to hex, you can do this:

```
    decoded.toString(16); //=> 27
```

Comment: +1 The only code based answer in the web. Very nice thank you. I used your approach to write a function which is in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this function derived from Ryan Wheale's solution to convert any numerical hex Html string to a friendly string:

```
function hexHtmlToString(str) {
    var REG_HEX = /&#x([a-fA-F0-9]+);/g;
    return str.replace(REG_HEX, function(match, grp){
        var num = parseInt(grp, 16);
        return String.fromCharCode(num);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var str = '&#x633;&#x644;&#x627;&#x645;';
console.log(hexHtmlToString(str)); //results: سلام
```