# Convert unicode entities to Japanese words/symbols using Java Script

Tags: javascript, unicode

Here is a simple example to illustrate the problem. Say I have an html page like below.

```
<html>

<head> <title> First page</title> </head>

<body> Hello : &#x78BA;&#x8A8D;</body>

</html>
```

When I open this page in browser I get below test:

```
Hello : 確認
```

I want to use java script to convert `&#x78BA;&#x8A8D;` to above symbols and assign it to a string variable. How It can be done. I looked through several posts on this site but can not find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Do you want to translate the characters from Japanese to English?

Comment: I want to covert &#x78BA;&#x8A8D to Japanese symbol as shown above and assign it to a variable in Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to decode hex code of html entities to text in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607969/how-to-decode-hex-code-of-html-entities-to-text-in-javascript)